# Artful kills desktop session with external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-gnome

Just installed Artful on my Dell XPS 9343 with hdd wiped. It was Xenial and fine.

When it is just the laptop (internal monitor), I see no problem.

But if I connected my external monitor and locked the screen, sometimes, when I trying to unlock, it appeared that my session was killed.

What I see:

1. Monitor is powersaving.
2. Hit keyboard.
3. Screen flashes once.
4. Login screen appears.
5. Login with the same user.
6. Lock screen appears.
7. Input password.
8. Get back to desktop, all windows gone.

Is there something I configured wrong?

Comment: It might be trouble with Wayland. Try switching to the X-based session instead when you login.

Comment: @muru, same thought. But still like to give wayland a try.

Comment: So would I, but my GDM itself crashes with dual monitors and I have to force it to use X just to log on

Comment: @muru, I think it is time to file a bug. I noticed a "core" file at home for Xwayland. From its time, seems like responding to the session killing.

Comment: @muru I built latest Xwayland to replace Artful one. Seems resolved the issue.